# nodeJS app as microservice for multiple web apps

Tags: javascript, node.js, microservices

I have a few applications. For each I need an authentication service, I have written this service separately. How is it possible to use this authentication service in different web applications?
The reason for separating is that I do not want to rewrite this service multiple times.

Would lerna.js be an idea to implement such a construct?

Or are there any more sensible solutions?

Comment: A micro service could be implemented in various ways. Each with their pros and cons. Your question is too broad to be answered.

Comment: Are you sure that you know what a microservice is? Based on your comment and on your mentioning of lerna.js it seems as if you might have some misunderstanding about that.

Answer (score 0):

So you are using microservice architecture where you have written a completely separate application for authentication. This is completely fine.

Now what you would do is, deploy all the microservices and let other services to use auth server for authentication. How would you do that? Well, you can do it using our friendly RESTful architecture. Lets say you have a service X. When you try to access X, X would send a request to Auth server. Auth server will response back to the service X if you have access or not. If you have access then X service would response you back with data or authentication error.

Do you get me?

Comment: Sorry, I wrote that a little bit incomprehensible. In every web application, I want to include this authentication service as a sub package.

I just want to get this service from the same repository.

Comment: Then you can create a package out of it and push it to a git repository. Then wherever you need  `npm install GIT_URL`.